# How to play a specific part of a video with PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, pyqt

I would like to play a certain part of a video, for example, play a video from second 30 to second 33 using PyQt5. I am using the Qmultimedia widget.

This is how my player code looks. Is there a way to start and end at a certain position? I've been manually clipping the video into subclips and just playing those subclips instead but that's very time consuming. Thank you!

```
self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(None, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
file = QtCore.QDir.current().filePath("path")
self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)))
self.player.setVideoOutput(self.ui.videoWidget)
self.player.play()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the position in ms with the `setPosition()` method, and through the `positionChanged` signal you can monitor the elapsed time to stop the playback

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        video_widget = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(video_widget)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(self, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.player.setVideoOutput(video_widget)
        # period of time that the change of position is notified
        self.player.setNotifyInterval(1)
        self.player.positionChanged.connect(self.on_positionChanged)

    def setInterval(self, path, start, end):
        """
            path: path of video
            start: time in ms from where the playback starts
            end: time in ms where playback ends
        """
        self.player.stop()
        self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)))
        self.player.setPosition(start)
        self._end = end
        self.player.play()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot('qint64')
    def on_positionChanged(self, position):
        if self.player.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            if position > self._end:
                self.player.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "test.mp4")
    w.setInterval(file, 30*1000, 33*1000)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```